# a checkmark on top of thumbnail for ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In Apple's Photos app, after one select each image there is a check-mark appear at the corner.  Is this a build-in function of iOS SDK?  Or this is a diy if one wants to accomplish to same effect.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a custom UIView implementation. I'd venture to guess that it's an extension of UIImageView (or even a UIView container) that adds a subview containing the check mark when it detects a tap.

Comment: Yes it might be a subclass or extension of UIImageView, you could subclass or create extension of it and add a subview to it once it's tapped.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a built-in functionality**. You have a list of buttons of constant frame size, and with in image embedded in it.You need to have an image of the tick mark, and allocate it with a frame size such that it comes to the bottom right half of the screen. Add it as a `subView` to the `imageView`.

It is actually done like this.

For `UIControlStateNormal` you have the image represented as it is seen before the checkmark. For the event, `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` the tick Mark Image is added as a subView to the previous image and shown.

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourstuff:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In the method `yourstuff:` you can add the subView for that image.